# How To Supply Constructor Argument To Other Methods In PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, object-oriented-database

I've following class:

```
class User {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'thefilenet');

    public function __construct($username) {
        // code code code
    }

    public function isVerified($username) {
       $q1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `Verified` FROM `_users` WHERE `Username` = '$username'");
        $verified = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)[0];
        return ($verified == 1) ? true : false;
    }

    public function thisThat($username) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

There are lots of methods as well which carry one same argument at least, $username supplied to constructor at the `$user = new User('myUserName');` time. Now I want to use these methods without supplying $username argument everytime.

Like, I should be able to do `$user->isVerified();` instead of `$user->isVerified('myUserName');`

How do I achieve this?

PS: `$username` argument is required in every method for dynamic table/record selection.

Comment: sorry, what your `$con=mysqli_connect()` doing between the class methods ?

Comment: Put the username in a class property in the constructor.

Comment: @OlegDubas I'm using this connection `$con` in different methods to retrieve data from mysql tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the `$username` you give to the constructor in a class private property for future use:

```
class User 
{
    private $username;

    function __construct($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    function isVerified() {
       // check $this->username
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah exactly I was looking for! So stupid it skipped out of my mind! Thanks! :)